# Flutter Web with Firebase, error "No module for dart_sdk.js"

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

When running Firebase on android, there is no problem, but when debugging on the web (chrome or edge), it doesn't work... in the Debug Console a DART_SDK.JS problem notification appears, like this:

"Locations: No module for http://localhost:53xxx/dart_sdk.js"

This notification only appears when running at **Firebase.initializeApp();**

My Code:

> ```
> void main() async {
>       WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
>       await Firebase.initializeApp();
>     
>       runApp(
>         MaterialApp(
>           title: "Firebase", 
>           home: MyApp()
>         )
>       );
>     }
> ```

Comment: have you found the answer for this?

Comment: I am getting the same error while running Flutter -version 3.3.4 on the stable channel.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone initializing with web information and still getting this error on
Flutter 3.3.1 • channel stable
Framework • revision 4f9d92f (20 hours ago) • 2022-09-06 17:54:53 -0700
Engine • revision 3efdf03e73
Tools • Dart 2.18.0 • DevTools 2.15.0
->Try changing channel to flutter channel stable
for that run these commands in flutter terminal

```
flutter channel master
flutter upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the application without debugging.
Flutter new release 3.3.4 maybe is not stable yet.
Reference link for the error : [Locations: No module for http://localhost:/dart_sdk.js](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/111136)

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you need to configure some extra things for web to work in your initializeApp method

```
 Platform.isAndroid? await Firebase.initializeApp():await Firebase.initializeApp(
        // Replace with actual values
        options: const FirebaseOptions(
          apiKey: "your api key from firebase console here ",
          appId: "your apid from firebase console here",
          messagingSenderId: "XXX",
          projectId: "your project id",
        ),
      );
```